# call a global function in directives in ng

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a function which i call more than once ( in different directives).

So is there a way to call a function in every directive?
One solution would be to make the function as a service. 
But the service does need a return value, doesn´t it?

```
 this.changeDesign = function (currentstep) {
             //do something
};
```

this method I call many times.

Comment: in an angularjs service you need to return the object containaing the functions of your service.

Comment: in the changeDesign I just add css Classes to elements

Comment: You can put the global function in `app.value` or `app.constant` and inject it and consume it. 

Ex:-

   `app.value('jQuery', window.jQuery)`. Dont have to necessarily use a service.

Comment: if you add a css class only, I think it's better to do it in a directive.

Comment: Can you give me an example pls. (maybe link)

Comment: @hic1086 : so you think I´ts ok when I wirte the same function in all directives`? I mean I would called it in directive.

Comment: yes. I've detailed that in my ansewr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider to avoid using global variables or put something on the global scope. Maybe it works now, but if your project gets bigger, you will probably get a lot of problems. More infos for example: https://gist.github.com/hallettj/64478

Here is an example, how you can use a factory, which you can inject into your directives (coding style inspired by John Papa https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#factories):

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular.module('my-app').provider('MyFactory', MyFactory);

    MyFactory.$inject = [];
    function MyFactory() {

        var service = {
            changeDesign: myChangeDesignImpl
        };

        function myChangeDesignImpl() { }

        this.$get = function() {
            return service ;
        };
}

})();
```

You can now inject your service into a directive like this:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

    angular.module('my-app').directive('MyDirective', MyDirective);

    MyDirective.$inject = ["MyFactory"];

    function MyDirective(MyFactory) {
       var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "/template.html",
            link: link
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, el, attr) {
            MyFactory.changeDesign();
       }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in a directive that you will delcare on your elements.

```
    angular.module('myDesignModule', [])
     .directive('myDesignDirective', function() {
          return {
               link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl){
               element.addClass("myClass");
            }

     };)
```